# Convert windows-1256 to utf-8 or utf-8 to windows-1256 in php

Tags: php, mysqli, lua, autoplay-media-studio

I created a program with lua on Autoplay Media Studio 8.5 and send some data to MySQL database

My database collation is utf8_unicode_ci and when i send data whit AMS it saved on table like this : ÓáÇã Çíä í˜ ÊÓÊ ÇÓÊ

When I use AMS to SELECT data and show there is no problem.

but I want to create a web page with php and SELECT data. In this case characters shows still like this : ÓáÇã Çíä í˜ ÊÓÊ ÇÓÊ

I use this code on my php file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $db_path = "localhost";
            $db_name = "mydb";
            $db_user = "root";
            $db_pass = "";

            $conn = mysqli_connect($db_path, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
            if ($conn->connect_error) {die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}

            mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'cp1256');

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";

            $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){echo $row['col1']}

            mysqli_close($conn);

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if your db is utf8 you shouldnt be saying this `mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'cp1256');`Instead, convert the values to utf 8 FIRST

Comment: thanks for your reply. but please help me how to convert to utf8 ?

Comment: sure, use this command http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: I can't open link

Comment: its the php manual, why are you anable to reach that?!?!?!

Comment: I change my code like that page sample : 
$row['col'] = mb_convert_encoding($row['col1'], "windows-1256", "utf-8");
but i get  Warning: mb_convert_encoding(): Unknown encoding "windows-1256

Comment: are you sure you dont mean 1252?

Comment: i don't know what is different but when i use AMS and set windows-1256 it shows my text normally

Comment: try converting from cp-1252 and see what happens

Comment: i tried but it didn't show my text normally